# How to sort price from high to low using Expedia API

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How to sort price desc order using `response.hotelList[i].lowRate`.

Code are like given:

```
success: function (response) {
        var bil = 1;
        var hotel_size = response.hotelList.length;

        $('#listData').append('<tr><td> Bil </td><td> Image </td><td> Hotel Name </td><td> Hotel Star Rating </td><td> Hotel Description </td><td> Price </td></tr>');  
        for (var i =0; i<hotel_size; i++) {
          //alert(response.hotelList[i].lowRate);
          for (var i =0; i <= response.hotelList[i].lowRate i++) {

          $('#listData').append('<tr><td>'+bil+'</td><td><img src="http://media.expedia.com'+response.hotelList[i].thumbnailUrl+'" style="width:100px;height:100px;"/></td><td>'+response.hotelList[i].name+'</td><td>'+ response.hotelList[i].hotelStarRating +'</td><td>'+response.hotelList[i].shortDescription+'</td><td>'+response.hotelList[i].lowRate+'</td></tr>');  
          bil++;
        }
      }
    },
```

Comment: You need to sort the list using a comparator function before injecting into the `DOM`. Also there might be support in the API which consumes the filter and return the list in the right order.

Comment: Im sorry sir/madam, i am new in coding. I hope you can give some code perhaps in js. Thank you for your kindness. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a sorted list of hotels using something like:

```
var hotels       = response.hotelList;
var sortedHotels = hotels.sort(function(a, b) { 
    return b.lowRate - a.lowRate;
})
```

And then have your for loop iterate through the sorted list and append html elements.

```
for (var i =0; i <= sortedHotels; i++) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Okay thank you sir. One more thing how we make the image by clciking on it can display hotel details? im apply for your kindness